# Copy gridview cell value to the clipboard

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with some values. If the user clicks on a link or button  (here I took a Buttonfield with the text 'Copy') on one of the rows, it should copy a cell value of that row to the clipboard.
Is something like this possible in asp.net c# ?

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="False"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                SortExpression="Username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" 
                SortExpression="Password" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="/images/edit.png" CancelImageUrl="/images/undo.png"  UpdateImageUrl="/images/save.png" ShowEditButton="True"   />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowDeleteButton="True"  DeleteImageUrl="/images/deletered.png"    />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Copy"  />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No data available
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

There is no Onclick event available for a ButtonField. Otherwise I would think of using some javascript (I have seen that in other solutions)
Thanks for any input.

Comment: http://zeroclipboard.org is one of the most popular libraries for cross-browser clipboard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with windows form only, but since you are working on Web application you should write client side code which is javascript to copy data on client side not server side. checkout [this](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard) link

Comment: Your answer looks more like a comment to me, since it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: The goal is to grab the e.Row.Cells[1].Text value and assign it to the "clipboard". Any practical example in asp.net would be very helpfull.